# Meteor 1.3 - render not triggered on props change

Tags: meteor, reactjs, meteor-react

I've recently updated to meteor 1.3 and I'm having trouble with the createContainer function. The app is supposed re-render when the props change, however, it's not happening. I'm working with the example from [this page](https://www.meteor.com/tutorials/react/collections) but nothing is happening, the app only displays the header. No errors are present.

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';
import { createContainer } from 'meteor/react-meteor-data';
import { Tasks } from '../api/tasks.js';


import Task from './Task.jsx';


class App extends Component {

  renderTasks() {
    return this.props.tasks.map((task) => (
      <Task key={task._id} task={task} />
    ));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <header>
          <h1>Header</h1>
        </header>

        <ul>
          {this.renderTasks()}
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}


App.propTypes = {
  tasks: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
};

export default createContainer(() => {
  return {
    tasks: Tasks.find({}).fetch(),
  };
}, App);
```

tasks.js:

```
import { Mongo } from 'meteor/mongo';

export const Tasks = new Mongo.Collection('tasks');
```

I've been stuck for longer for more than I'm willing to admit, what am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Your `renderTasks` method has no idea what `this` is, since React classes do not do auto-binding. Modify your component to be this instead:

```
class App extends Component {
  renderTasks() {
    return this.props.tasks.map((task) => (
      <Task key={task._id} task={task} />
    ));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <header>
          <h1>Header</h1>
        </header>

        <ul>
          {this.renderTasks.call(this)}
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Or alternatively, you could do `meteor npm install --save react-autobind` and insert this constructor which will automatically bind everything for you:

```
import autoBind from 'react-autobind';

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    autoBind(this);
  }

  // ...
}
```

Comment: I tried your solution, but unfortunately that's not it :(

Comment: Have you tried any `console.log` statements? Place one just inside `render() {`: `console.log(this.props.tasks)` and see what it spits out.

Comment: Also, just to keep things simple while debugging, I'd replace your `<Task>` with just a `<div>` for now.

Comment: It's silly, but it turns out during migration I accidentally put my server code inside my client folder. I'm not sure why that didn't cause any errors, but it turned out to be the cause of this bug. Thanks for help though!

Answer (score 0):

It had nothing to do with the code and everything to do with me accidentally placing my server code inside the client code while migrating to Meteor 1.3

I'm not sure why this didn't cause any errors though.

Answer (score -1):

It's missing the reference of React:

```
App.propTypes = {
  tasks: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
};
```

to

```
App.propTypes = {
  tasks: React.PropTypes.array.isRequired,
};
```

Comment: This answer is in error: The original code does bring `PropTypes` into scope with an `import` statement. So this does not answer the question.